# c++ strcpy ошибка

Tags: c++, структуры

Есть массив структур:

```
struct schoolboy
{
public:
    char firstName[30];
    char secondName[30];
    char addres[50];
    int schoolNumber;
    int schoolclass;
    schoolboy input(schoolboy *base);
    schoolboy recording(schoolboy *base, schoolboy *record, int number);
};
```

Вот реализация:

```
int main(){
    int number;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    cout << "Введите число " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    schoolboy base[28], record[28], a;

    a.input(base);
    a.recording(base, record, number);
    recordOut(record);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

А вот проблемная функция, проблема именно в `strcpy`:

```
schoolboy schoolboy::recording(schoolboy *base, schoolboy *record, int 
number)
{
if (base->schoolNumber == number)
{
    if (base->schoolclass==10 || base->schoolclass==11)
    {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        strcpy(record[i].firstName, base[i].firstName);  //тут ошибка
        strcpy(record[i].secondName , base[i].secondName);
        strcpy(record[i].addres, base[i].addres);
    }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Haven't 10 or 11 class" << endl;
        return *base;
    }
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "Not found" << endl;
    return *base;
 }
 return *record;
```

Как исправить ошибку? И не могли бы вы дать советы по реализации в «мэйне» ф-ий из структур.

Ошибка:

> ```
> error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
> Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
> ```

Comment: Это не ошибка, это винда (диагноз ...)

Comment: @avp: При чем здесь "винда"?

Comment: @AnT, да в общем при том же, что и в выборе CP-1251 или `'\'` вместо `'/'` и т.п. проектировании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени все strcpy на strcpy_s.

Comment: работает, но в чём отличия и почему возникла проблема?

Comment: @Андрей, `strcpy_s` — [безопасная](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136185/difference-between-strcpy-and-strcpy-s) версия `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите разбираться с заморочками студии, есть еще один способ. В настройках проекта указать как предопределенный макрос вот это:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Или можно добавить это в начало файла.

Comment: Добавлять это следует не "в самом верху файла", а глобально в настройках проекта.